# Java -version still showing 1.6 even after installing 1.7

Tags: java

I am new to java and I installed JDk 7 using

> sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre

But when I do java -version I get this

> ```
> java version "1.6.0_26"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
> Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
> ```

How do I set it to 1.7 and also how do I set my compiler to 1.7 in eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

You may use the following command to change the default java version:  `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

I think eclipse will use the default java version, but you may take a look at "Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler"